# Update only the time portion of a MySQL TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have a TIMESTAMP column containing:

```
2011-10-12 12:00:00
```

Now I want to be able to take user input to change the time only, and not the date. So, if the user inputs `5:00 pm` I first convert the input to `17:00:00`, then my problem is UPDATING the TIMESTAMP to `2011-10-12 17:00:00` without overwriting the date. The user can pick any time, but they are restricted to this day, and I need to store the date and time in the same column like this because it's already used in many other parts of the application.

Note: I would prefer not to SELECT the `TIMESTAMP` first before updating if it's possible to UPDATE just the TIME portion without a SELECT.

I looked at DATE TIME functions and there are lots of ways of adding an interval to the time, but I don't see anyway to set it to something specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE tab 
SET ts_field = ADDTIME(DATE(ts_field), new_time) 
WHERE id = ?;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
update table 
set datetime_field = concat_ws(' ',date(datetime_field), '17:00:00') where id = x
```